# Magento adminhtm filter limit

Tags: magento, url, magento-1.7, limit

I'm running a Magento webshop (version 1.7.0.2, behind a login). Currently it's required to set individual orders to the state 'shipped'. The problem is not the action itself, but the selection of the orders. It takes a lot of time to select all orders through the order admin page.

There are multiple ways to achieve it, but so far I've chosen to implemented the following adminhtml page: http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-multiselect-and-filter-in-magento-admin-grids-in-and-not-in/. It allows to search for multiple items at once from the order page. But I'm running in an issue: all search parameters are included in the URL. Example:

```
http://example.com/magentodir/index.php/admin/sales_order/grid/filter/cmVhbF9vcmRlcl9pZD0xMDAwMDA1NTclMkMxMDAwMDA1NTgxMDAwMDA1NTclMkMxMDAwMDA1NTkmY3JlYXRlZF9hdCU1QmxvY2FsZSU1RD1lbl9VUw==/?ajax=true&isAjax=true
```

The server aparently restricts this to 255 caracters. Beyond that length I receive a 400 bad request error. I could up the server limit to about 2048, but that's still very limited solution

Question: Is it possible to force Magento to include the filter options in the POST part of the AJAX action?

I'm also surprised that I could not find any other person with the same issue. Or has this perhaps been changed in later Magento versions?